# WPF WrapPanel HorizontalContentAlignment

Tags: wpf, alignment, wrappanel

Is there a way to make all item in WrapPanel alignment to center?

WrapPanel Normal Behavior

```
|1234567  |
|890      |
```

Desired Behavior

```
| 1234567 |
|   890   |
```

Possible duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806777/wpf-how-can-i-center-all-items-in-a-wrappanel)

I just don't understand how to use the code on the answer (on link).

Comment: looks like this Question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806777/wpf-how-can-i-center-all-items-in-a-wrappanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is a custom WrapPanel. just copy it into an empty class and be sure to set all the `using` classes at the first lines.

Use this custom panel as you use a normal WrapPanel. (in Xaml is a little bit different).
in this panel there is an extra propert: `HorizontalContentAlignment`. Its default value is `HorizontalAlignment.Left`. You should set `HorizontalAlignment=HorizontalAlignment.Center`.

There is no need to deal with MeasureOverride or ArrangeOverride methods.

Comment: There's no such property.