# Windows Phone - How can I center all items in a WrapPanel?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, wpftoolkit, wrappanel

I'm using a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate of a ListBox.The items in the control wrap like this:

```
|1234567  |
|890      |
```

I'd like them to wrap like this:

```
| 1234567 |
|   890   |
```

I found this link [WPF - How can I center all items in a WrapPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806777/wpf-how-can-i-center-all-items-in-a-wrappanel)
but the exemple is for WPF (I don't find FrameworkPropertyMetadata and FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions).

Comment: here you could set left alignment

Comment: may be this article will help you http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=176

Comment: This isn't what I need. I have update the image in the first post, maybe now you understand better.

Comment: You should use the Silverlight sample produced at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788145/416518. Windows Phone is a pared down distribution of Silverlight 4.