# How to achieve even horizontal spacing in ListView and WrapPanel template?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Heres example:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewItemSpacing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ListViewItemSpacing.Controls"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewItemSpacing"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Background="#222">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.Items>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            </ListView.Items>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This `XAML` produces 6 blue squares, 4 in the first row, 2 in the next row. After 4 first blue squares there is some space on the right.

In other words - it looks like left aligned text.

I want it to look like justified text, so I want the horizontal spacing between the squares adjusted to align `ListView` to left and right, space evenly distributed between elements, not on the right side.

Although it looks trivial to do, I don't know how to do it. I don't know where to even start. For example - I can see some spacing added by default. Ugly by default, because horizontal spacing is much greater than vertical, but it's not big enough to align the items to both left and right side. But where does the spacing come from? How to change it even manually? I don't want to mess with the elements themselves. Elements in real world app would come from different module and those modules should be well separated.

Most obvious thought is to handle `SizeChanged` event of the `ListView` and adjust horizontal spacing manually, however - WHERE is the spacing? I mean how can I access items spacing in code behind?

To clarify: the desired rendering should still contain 6 identical blue squares, but first 4 aligned to left and right control edge, the remaining 2 aligned to the left and to previous row squares.

Default look is like this:

```
----------------
|[] [] [] []   | 
|[] []         |
----------------
```

Desired look is like this:

```
----------------
|[]  []  []  []| 
|[]  []        |
----------------
```

Comment: i remember i have seen a similar wpf question about wrapPanel earlier this year. that question even had a bounty. it can be a dupe but unfortunately i can't find it right now

Comment: You said in a comment you know the `Width` of items, so you could consider a Converter. Pass it the available width and item width, then have the converter take `AvailableWidth / ItemWidth = numOfItems; AvailableWidth % ItemWidth = remainingSpace; remainingSpace / numOfItems = extraSpacePerItem;` and assign that however you want it. Probably Divide by 2 and put that amount on the Left/Right margins of each item.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps [this custom Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7747002/302677) would work for you? It's built to behave like a WrapPanel, except also has the ability to Align Content.

Comment: I tested it, however it doesn't support `Stretch` value for `HorizontalContentAlignment`. I'll try to see how it works, maybe I'll be able to fix this.

Comment: I tried to add margins to items in the first attempt. It didn't work correctly. It just behaved weird. However the `AlignableWrapPanel` turned out to be the the right clue to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel) and [DTig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164691/dtig) I finally made it. It seems like there's no panel capable of aligning elements like `WrapPanel` but with customizable `HorizontalContentAlignment`. And obviously - `HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch` is what I needed here.

Following [Rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel) advice I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806777/wpf-how-can-i-center-all-items-in-a-wrappanel/7747002#7747002), but it didn't support `HorizontalAlignment.Stretch` value.

So I added the support, which works provided element widths are equal to each other:

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="Panel"/> like <see cref="WrapPanel"/> which supports <see cref="HorizontalContentAlignment"/> property.
/// </summary>
public class AlignableWrapPanel : Panel {

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="HorizontalAlignment"/> property definition.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HorizontalContentAlignment",
            typeof(HorizontalAlignment),
            typeof(AlignableWrapPanel),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(HorizontalAlignment.Left, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange)
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the horizontal alignment of the control's content.
    /// </summary>
    [BindableAttribute(true)]
    public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalContentAlignment {
        get { return (HorizontalAlignment)GetValue(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Measures the size in layout required for child elements and determines a size for the <see cref="AlignableWrapPanel"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="constraint">The available size that this element can give to child elements. Infinity can be specified as a value to indicate that the element will size to whatever content is available.</param>
    /// <returns>The size that this element determines it needs during layout, based on its calculations of child element sizes.</returns>
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint) {
        var curLineSize = new Size();
        var panelSize = new Size();
        var children = base.InternalChildren;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.Count; i++) {
            var child = children[i] as UIElement;
            // Flow passes its own constraint to children
            child.Measure(constraint);
            var sz = child.DesiredSize;
            if (curLineSize.Width + sz.Width > constraint.Width) { //need to switch to another line
                panelSize.Width = Math.Max(curLineSize.Width, panelSize.Width);
                panelSize.Height += curLineSize.Height;
                curLineSize = sz;
                if (sz.Width > constraint.Width) { // if the element is wider then the constraint - give it a separate line                    
                    panelSize.Width = Math.Max(sz.Width, panelSize.Width);
                    panelSize.Height += sz.Height;
                    curLineSize = new Size();
                }
            }
            else { //continue to accumulate a line
                curLineSize.Width += sz.Width;
                curLineSize.Height = Math.Max(sz.Height, curLineSize.Height);
            }
        }
        // the last line size, if any need to be added
        panelSize.Width = Math.Max(curLineSize.Width, panelSize.Width);
        panelSize.Height += curLineSize.Height;
        return panelSize;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Positions child elements and determines a size for a <see cref="AlignableWrapPanel"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arrangeBounds">The final area within the parent that this element should use to arrange itself and its children.</param>
    /// <returns>The actual size used.</returns>
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds) {
        var firstInLine = 0;
        var curLineSize = new Size();
        var accumulatedHeight = 0.0;
        var children = InternalChildren;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.Count; i++) {
            var sz = children[i].DesiredSize;
            if (curLineSize.Width + sz.Width > arrangeBounds.Width) { //need to switch to another line
                ArrangeLine(accumulatedHeight, curLineSize, arrangeBounds.Width, firstInLine, i);
                accumulatedHeight += curLineSize.Height;
                curLineSize = sz;
                if (sz.Width > arrangeBounds.Width) { //the element is wider then the constraint - give it a separate line                    
                    ArrangeLine(accumulatedHeight, sz, arrangeBounds.Width, i, ++i);
                    accumulatedHeight += sz.Height;
                    curLineSize = new Size();
                }
                firstInLine = i;
            }
            else { //continue to accumulate a line
                curLineSize.Width += sz.Width;
                curLineSize.Height = Math.Max(sz.Height, curLineSize.Height);
            }
        }
        if (firstInLine < children.Count)
            ArrangeLine(accumulatedHeight, curLineSize, arrangeBounds.Width, firstInLine, children.Count);
        return arrangeBounds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Arranges elements within a line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="y">Line vertical coordinate.</param>
    /// <param name="lineSize">Size of the items line.</param>
    /// <param name="boundsWidth">Width of the panel bounds.</param>
    /// <param name="start">Index of the first child which belongs to the line.</param>
    /// <param name="end">Index of the last child which belongs to the line.</param>
    private void ArrangeLine(double y, Size lineSize, double boundsWidth, int start, int end) {
        var children = InternalChildren;
        var x = 0.0;
        var stretchOffset = 0.0;
        if (HorizontalContentAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Center) x = (boundsWidth - lineSize.Width) / 2;
        else if (HorizontalContentAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Right) x = (boundsWidth - lineSize.Width);
        else if (HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Stretch) {
            var childWidth = children[start].DesiredSize.Width; // warning, this works only when all children have equal widths
            int n = (int)boundsWidth / (int)childWidth;
            if (children.Count > n) {
                var takenWidth = n * childWidth;
                var spaceWidth = boundsWidth - takenWidth;
                stretchOffset = spaceWidth / (n - 1);
            }
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, child.DesiredSize.Width, lineSize.Height));
            x += child.DesiredSize.Width + stretchOffset;
        }
    }

}
```

This is basically [Tig's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164691/dtig) solution with `Stretch` alignment added.

Here's test XAML for this:

```
<Window
    x:Class="ListViewItemSpacing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewItemSpacing"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="250"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Background="#222">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <c:AlignableWrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.Items>
                <Rectangle
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Fill="#27f" />
                <Rectangle
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Fill="#27f" />
                <Rectangle
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Fill="#27f" />
                <Rectangle
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Fill="#27f" />
                <Rectangle
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Fill="#27f" />
                <Rectangle
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Fill="#27f" />
            </ListView.Items>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It's not perfect, but it does the specific job just perfectly. It won't work properly if the sizes of child elements would be different - in such case `takenWidth` should be calculated as sum of children with indices from `start` to `end`. You should also specify a different condition for the last line.

Thanks again, kind strangers :)

Comment: Glad you found a working solution, and thanks for sharing it for others seeking the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Let say we don't know the number of columns. The complete code for the windows xaml and code behind (Fix the class name to match your own). Try this:

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="SO39640127.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:so39640127="clr-namespace:SO39640127"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="{Binding LayoutHeight, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Width="{Binding LayoutWidth,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance so39640127:MainWindow}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Background="#222" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                 Columns="{Binding LayoutColumns, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                 Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"></UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.Items>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="{Binding ItemWidth}" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}" Margin="{Binding VerticalSpacing}"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="{Binding ItemWidth}" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}" Margin="{Binding VerticalSpacing}"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="{Binding ItemWidth}" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}" Margin="{Binding VerticalSpacing}"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="{Binding ItemWidth}" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}" Margin="{Binding VerticalSpacing}"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="{Binding ItemWidth}" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}" Margin="{Binding VerticalSpacing}"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#27f" Width="{Binding ItemWidth}" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}" Margin="{Binding VerticalSpacing}"/>
            </ListView.Items>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double itemHeight;
        private double itemWidth;
        private int layoutColumns;
        private int layoutHeight;
        private int layoutWidth;
        private Thickness verticalSpacing;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            InitializeDesign();
        }

        public double ItemWidth
        {
            get { return itemWidth; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Equals(itemWidth))
                    return;
                itemWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double ItemHeight
        {
            get { return itemHeight; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Equals(itemHeight))
                    return;
                itemHeight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int LayoutColumns
        {
            get { return layoutColumns; }
            set
            {
                if (value == layoutColumns)
                    return;
                layoutColumns = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int LayoutWidth
        {
            get { return layoutWidth; }
            set
            {
                if (value == layoutWidth)
                    return;
                layoutWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                UpdateCalculations();
            }
        }

        public int LayoutHeight
        {
            get { return layoutHeight; }
            set
            {
                if (value == layoutHeight)
                    return;
                layoutHeight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                UpdateCalculations();
            }
        }

        public Thickness VerticalSpacing
        {
            get { return verticalSpacing; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Equals(verticalSpacing))
                    return;
                verticalSpacing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void UpdateCalculations()
        {
            //Calculate the # of elements that fit on the list view
            var totalItems = (int) (LayoutWidth/ItemWidth);
            LayoutColumns = totalItems;
        }

        private void InitializeDesign()
        {
            LayoutWidth = 525;
            LayoutHeight = 350;

            ItemWidth = 100;
            ItemHeight = 100;

            VerticalSpacing = new Thickness(3);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I'm achieving vertical spacing through margin in the items. You can try resizing in order to see how the columns adjust correctly depending on the dimensions of the window. Also, I'm using a little bit of MVVM to do the bindings for demo purposes. You should of course adapt it accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I don't know the number of columns because it depends on the window size. I know element width and height however. I can calculate the number of columns in `SizeChanged` event handler. Another problem the vertical spacing dependent on control's height and items count.

Comment: How'd you like to handle vertical spacing? Should be evenly distributed also? Or you'd rather have it top-aligned?

Comment: Exactly like in justified text: the vertical spacing is totally separate from horizontal spacing or horizontal alignment. `WrapPanel` seems like the way to go. I figured out how to change the spacing, I haven't figured how to calculate correct spacing values and how to pass them to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` without using an ugly hack. BTW: Item size is known, window size is unknown, the number of items is unknown.

Comment: I might be missing something specific to your context. I'm editing my answer so you could give it a shot to this approach. Let me know what do you think?