# Text wrapping single word when no space is available isn't working

Tags: wpf, xaml, formatting, word-wrap

A single word doesn't wrap to a new line even though there is no space to fit all of the word on the current line. Is there a way I can force it to do so? This is demonstrated on the left hand side image. When a whitespace is introduced the system will wrap how I want to to. See right hand side.

[image: Left: "Email" text is displayed behind "Notification Channel", but split in two lines "Ema" and "il"; Right: "Email Or Phone" text is displayed below the "Notification Channel" text.]

The XAML:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=SummaryStackPanel, Path=ActualWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Edit: The problem with using a wrap panel is you can't align the content. **Previously I didn't show this, but the values that don't need to wrap at all need to be right aligned.** It appears that wrap panel doesn't allow you to align content out of the box [WPF - How can I center all items in a WrapPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806777/wpf-how-can-i-center-all-items-in-a-wrappanel)

Wrap Panel (left) Vs Grid (right)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The same behavior is reproducible with one and multiple words. You use a `Grid` which has two columns. The horizontal space is divided between both. One `TextBlock` on the left, one on the right. Color the columns and you see that the space is honored by both. The `TextBlock` can only overflow in its own column, not another one.

[image: Left: Red area containing text; Right: Green area containing wrapped text.]

However, you could use a [`WrapPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead, so the whole `TextBlock` is moved down, when there is not enough space. After it is moved down and the available space decreases further, the text will start to wrap.

```
<WrapPanel  Width="{Binding ElementName=SummaryStackPanel, Path=ActualWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="8,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextAlignment="Right"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Compared to the approach with a `Grid`, the `TextBlock` is moved in this colored example.

[image: Left: Red area containing text; Right: Green area containing text.]

[image: Top: Red area containing text; Bottom: Green area containing text.]

Comment: Hi @thatguy Thanks for the detailed response. I've updated my original question with some important information that I previously didn't think was going to be important